# How can I get a work visa for US?

Tags: usa, working-visas, immigration

I'm a tech engineer and want to work in the US but I am struggling to get a work visa. I don't understand which visas I would be eligible for or how to obtain them.

Comment: Welcome Samiksha. Work permits for the US are never easy but how hard depends on where you are from, how high your education, how much work experience and more details. I will move your question to our brother site for Expatriates, but you should add details like your nationality and your education and experience.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,  you should have a U.S. or foreign equivalent bachelor degree.

Secondary,you need to find a sponsored employer in the U.S. who will file H1B visa on your behalf.

Once your petition got approved, you will be able to work in the U.S. up to 3 years, even immigrant based on your employment.

Luckily, your employment  type is within STEM(science,technology,engineering, and mathematics) field, you will be more likely to get your visa approved than the others.